# Relative image path not working(HTML)

Tags: html

I cant seem to get my image to display on my webpage using a relative path. Im using the program "brackets" to do all of my editing before uploading to the webpage. Below is the relative path that i'm using and when I hover over the path the image thumbnail displays. but it still wont display on the page... am I missing anything? please and thank you.

```
<img id="01" class ="tn leftcol" width = "150" height = "150" 
src=".//Images/IMG_3604.JPG" alt="1" />
```

Comment: change `src=".//Images/IMG_3604.JPG" alt="1" /> ` to `src="./Images/IMG_3604.JPG" alt="1" /> ` see if it works

Comment: Why not just `src="Images/IMG_3604.JPG"`, without the leading stuff?

Comment: if you have the folder structure like:
.Project ->
 index.html, 
 .Images

you just need to do "Images/image.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

there are two slashes. this can be interpreted as a protocol. Change the `src` to  `Images/IMG_3604.JPG`

If this is being populated via a variable, check the source text or environments

Answer (score 0):

There are two forward slashes. It should be ./Images/xxxxx.png not .//

Answer (score 0):

If you have to go out of a directory, use ../ if the image folder is in the folder you are currently in use nothing.

Src="Images/IMG_3604.JPG"

Your html file is in the same directory.

Src="../Images/IMG_3604.JPG"

Html file is in a subdirectory and you need to go outside of that folder to get to images.

Src="../../Images/IMG_3604.JPG"

Html is in a subdirectory of a subdirectory and you need to go outside of both to get to the Images folder.

Hope this helps.